# How can I overload static methods and use generic type constraints

Tags: f#, type-constraints

Given the following type with its overloaded methods

```
type ToOptionString = ToOptionString
with
    static member ($) (_: ToOptionString, l: string) : Option<string> = Some l
    static member ($) (_: ToOptionString, l: Option<string>) : Option<string> = l
    static member ($) (_: ToOptionString, l: Option<int>) : Option<string> = 
       l |>> sprintf "%A"

let inline toOptionString v = ToOptionString $ v
```

which compiles fine in itself

However if I use the function `toOptionString` in another module like this

```
let x = toOptionString (Some 1)
```

I get the following error

```
A unique overload for method 'op_Dollar' could not be determined based on 
type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be 
needed. Candidates: 
static member ToOptionString.( $ ) : ToOptionString * l:Option<int> -> Option<string>, 
static member ToOptionString.( $ ) : ToOptionString * l:Option<string> -> Option<string>

val toOptionString : v:'a -> '_arg3 (requires member ( $ ))
```

So it seems to me that when overloading I must not use types with generic type parameters. Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: I guess the operator ``|>>`` comes from F#+, if so I can confirm that your example compiles fine for me. Try to find something that reproduces the error, which seems to be an ambiguity between the overloads.

Comment: yeah that is from fsharpplus. But that is definitely not the issue. You could return simply a constant value like `Some "foo"` and it still causes that error at the call site

Comment: As I said, I don't get any error. I tried with F# 4.0 and F# 4.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: I use 4.0. Have u used `toOptionString` in a different module? It works for me in the same module

Comment: Yes, [here's a repro](https://gist.github.com/gmpl/56dce5d400763944a6cef40d6c3b3fad) but works fine.

Comment: Can you try it with a .fsproj and .fs files instead of .fsx?

Comment: The toOptionString signature seems to suggest that it was not inline. I get:
val inline toOptionString :
  v: ^a ->  ^_arg3
    when (ToOptionString or  ^a) : (static member ( $ ) : ToOptionString * ^a ->  ^_arg3)

Comment: I tried in a project, different modules, different .fs files and works fine

Comment: OK, I got a bit closer. I have a structure similar to this `v |> pick |> toOptionString` where `pick :: Brand2<SomeType,'b,'c> -> 'b option` 
is an generic inline function that than calls other generic and inlined functions (3 in total) and it seems like the type inferrer is not able to sort that many inline generic functions in a row.
If I call `let x = toOptionString (Some 1)` then it does work (I dont know why it didn't work first)

Comment: @robkuz As from your description it could be many things, including F# bugs in the constraint solver, but if you want a precise answer you need to post a minimal complete sample code which can be easily evaluated to show the problem, including your generic function ``pick``.